# Remove stringFormat while editing cell in datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to remove a string format of a cell while I'm editing it because it's causing side effects. Actually, it's moving my cursor while I'm editing the cell.

Here is my code :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="15*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" 
Header="Coût (k€)" Binding="{Binding Path=TechnicalCostAmount, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N0, ConverterCulture=fr-FR}"/>
```

I think I've to do something with the EditingElementStyle property but I don't find anything on the Web to do it.

Hope you could help me.

Cheers
Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could use a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Coût (k€)">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TechnicalCostAmount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N0, ConverterCulture=fr-FR}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TechnicalCostAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: This a good approach, too.  There are lots of different ways to accomodate these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options. Two of which are:

1. Change your binding to ignore stringformat and move it to your ViewModel/Model
2. Create a custom Value Converter

Changing your binding is the simplest, however **least reusable**:

Update the binding in XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Width="15*" 
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" 
    Header="Coût (k€)" 
    Binding="{Binding Path=TechnicalCostAmount, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Then in your ViewModel/Model:

```
public string TechnicalCostAmount
{
    get { return string.Format("{0:n0}", _TechnicalCostAmount); }
    set 
    { 
       Decimal.TryParse(value, _TechnicalCostAmount);
       RaisePropertyChange("TechnicalCostAmount");
    }
}
```

**Creating a custom value converter does the same thing as the code above, however it allows you to use it in multiple places.**

See: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html